# How to see if list contains three or more of same element?

Tags: python, list, integer

If the list contains exactly three elements to n, it will return a Boolean True. If not, it will return a Boolean false. It's like a three of a kind game. The list also has to have a range of 1-6 and length of 1-6 characters. I have this part figured out, but I don't know how to count the number of times an integer appears in the list. I have this but it's not right at all, anything would help!

```
    def threeOfAKind(aList,n):
        if 1<=len(aList)<=6 and set(aList)<=set(range(1,6)):
            for n=>3 in aList:
        return True
```

I do not want it to return the count of the list. I want it to return Boolean True or False.

Comment: use python [count](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_count.htm)

Comment: You ought to follow the [PEP8 naming convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions): replace names by `three_of_a_kind`, `a_list`...

Comment: Notice that function parameters and local variables have the same scope: so `aList=[]` overrides the parameter of the same name.

Comment: You need [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)